# Array inside an Array: Different syntax for Array in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, gnu, bash-array

I found the following example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453656/3503228). But I can't understand how is array `arr` is being defined.

```
a='domain.de;de;https'
$ arr=(${a//;/ })
```

What is the advantage of defining it like this?

Actually, I want to store an array inside an array of varying size like as follows:

```
declare -a Workspace=(
    "${Folder[0]}"  "CFD"   "General,Markdown"
    "${Folder[4]}"  "GPU"   "General,Markdown,Python,C,Java"
)
```

For example in above, I want to access the terms `General` and `Markdown` for `CFD`.

Comment: Just because you *can* make an array of space delimited elements in bash doesn't make it a good idea. A good fat structure is important, and if the problem is this complex, consider a more powerful and flexible language like Perl.

Answer (score 2):

An array of arrays is a bad idea in shell (any shell). You need some other language.

> how is array `arr` being defined.?
>
> ```
> a='domain.de;de;https'
> arr=(${a//;/ })
> ```

It works by:

- replacing every `;` by an `space`
- Assuming IFS is space, tab, newline (the default)
- splitting on space (included in IFS) the **unquoted** expansion of `${...}`
- assigning it to an array `(...)`
- and naming that array `arr=`.

> What is the advantage of defining it like this?

None, only problems:

- If any of the elements contains an space, a tab or a newline, it will be split.
- As globbing was not turn off, any `*`, `?` or `[ ]` will be expanded to matching files.
- If nullglob is active, any string containing `*`,`?` or `[ ]` will be removed.
- if failglob is active any of the previous characters will generate an error.

In short, splitting on the shell is full of gotchas.